# Ionic2 `service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService()` <= cannot find 'google'

Tags: google-maps, ionic2

> EDIT: adding `var google : any;` to the global scope of autocomplete.ts did not solve the issue, just deffered it by a bit.

After dealing with this and following several forums for this error and implementing every npm install, both --save-dev to global.

-I've installed `google-maps` and `@types/googlemaps` in the package.json devDependencies', i've also installed the global typeings npm which I later used to install another dt-google.maps file, I've pretty much done everything and it's still showing `cannot find 'google'`.

I think it's a package issue, if i'm wrong -correct me.

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "githubIonic",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.7.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.2.0",
    "typescript": "2.2.1",
    "google-maps": "^3.2.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.26.11"

  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

And

#### src/pages/autocomplete/autocomplete.ts

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import {ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, GoogleMapsLatLng } from 'ionic-native';
/**
 * Generated class for the AutocompletePage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-autocomplete',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete.html',
})
export class AutocompletePage {
  autocompleteItems;
  autocomplete;

  service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();

  constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController, private zone: NgZone, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.autocompleteItems = [];
    this.autocomplete = {
      query: ''
    };
  }

  dismiss() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }
  chooseItem(item: any) {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(item);
  }
  updateSearch() {
    if (this.autocomplete.query == '') {
      this.autocompleteItems = [];
      return;
    }
    let me = this;
    this.service.getPlacePredictions({
      input: this.autocomplete.query,
      componentRestrictions: {country: 'TH'}
    }, function (predictions, status) {
      me.autocompleteItems = [];
      me.zone.run(function () {
        predictions.forEach(function (prediction) {
          me.autocompleteItems.push(prediction.description);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad AutocompletePage');
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you already tried by adding `declare var google: any;` right below the imports? This is just typescript complaining about knowing nothing about google and what it is...I'm using it exactly like this and works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a bit late but I hat the same issue. What I did was

1. First I installed typings
   `npm install -g typings@latest`

   on linux maybe

   `sudo npm install -g typings@latest`
2. the next step is to install the google maps typings:

   `typings install dt~google.maps --global`
3. Then I had to add the following line to the tsconfig.json file

   under "include": [ 
   // something like "src/**/*.ts" 
   `, "typings/*.d.ts"`
   ]

Answer (score -1):

Include Google Maps API in your `index.html`

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>`

And then declare google var in your typescript file see below.

`declare var google;
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-autocomplete',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete.html',
})`

you can also refer this blog: [Google Maps Autocomplete for Ionic 2 applications](http://devfanaticblog.com/google-maps-autocomplete-for-ionic-2-applications/)

Comment: I did every thing in that tutorial and also added what you wrote, same error.

Let me know what to paste into my question, if any needed.